# I need help making changes to a text file in java

Tags: java, database, text, savechanges

I am working on my project for intro to programming. The program is supposed to use a text file as a database to store first names, last names, and phone numbers. The program needs to be able to manipulate the data on the text file.

[Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixXZ4.png)

Here is my entire code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.nio.*;

public class Project
{
private static Scanner input;
private static Formatter x;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String choice = "";
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Please choose one of the following commands:%nL (Listing), I (insert), S (search), D (delete)%nM (modify), W (write), Q (quit with saving)");

    loop: while (choice != "Q") {
        System.out.printf("%nEnter your Command: ");
        choice = userInput.nextLine();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case "L":
                Listing();
                break;

            case "I":
                Insert();
                break;

            case "S":
                break;

            case "D":
                break;

            case "M":
                break;

            case "W":
                break;

            case "Q":
                break loop;
        } // end switch statement
    } // end while loop
} // end method main

public static void Listing() // List records from MiniDB.txt file
{
    try {
            File file = new File("MiniDB.txt");
            input = new Scanner(file);
        } 
    catch (IOException ioException) {
     System.err.println("Cannot open file.");
     System.exit(1);
        }
        if (input.hasNext()) { // If there are records in the file print them, else print none found
            while (input.hasNext()) // while there is more to read
            {
                String firstName = input.next();
                String lastName = input.next();
                String phoneNumber = input.next();

            System.out.printf("%-13s%-13s%s%n", firstName + ",", lastName, phoneNumber); }
            }
        else {
            System.out.printf("No records found");
        }
} // end method Listing

public static void Insert() // insert a record
{
    try {
            String file = "MiniDB.txt";
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true) );

            System.out.printf("Last Name: ");
            String lastName = input.next();
            System.out.printf("%nFirst Name: ");
            String firstName = input.next();
            System.out.printf("%nTelephone Number: ");
            String phoneNumber = input.next();

            outputStream.printf("%n%s %s %s", firstName, lastName, phoneNumber);
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.printf("%nDone.");
    } 
    catch (IOException ioException) {
     System.err.println("Cannot open file.");
     System.exit(1);
    }
} // end method Insert

public static void Search(); // search a record
{

}
} // end class Project
```

What I need help with is understanding how to create the "write" command. Currently, my code makes the changes to the text file automatically, but I need it to finalize changes only when W is inputted. I've been reading for awhile on this and I'm completely stuck. Do I need to rewrite what I have?

I was thinking about making all the changes on a temp.txt file and then if W is inputted, renaming temp.txt MiniDB.txt and overwriting that file. I would then need to delete the temp.txt file. I feel like there should be an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

For a basic solution why don't you keep the database in memory then update that. When the update is complete just write the in memory version to a file

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are taking the wrong approach to solving this. If you are supposed to write the file on a command (W) then the best solution is to hold the list of numbers in memory and then write it out again when the user asks for it.

So something like:

```
class Entry {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
}

List<Entry> entries;
```

When you receive a 'W' command you can iterate through the list of entries and write each one to the file.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep your data at temp using some memory object
and write changes to your DB when you finalize .

I have modified the above code as per your requirements
Kindly check

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Project {
    private static Scanner input;
    static JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    static String choice = "";
    static int i = 0;
    final static String file_path = "d:\\1\\MiniDB.txt";

    public static void menu() throws IOException, JSONException {
        System.out.println("Please choose one of the following commands:");
        System.out.println("L (Listing)");
        System.out.println("I (Insert)");
        System.out.println("D (delete)");
        System.out.println("S (search)");
        System.out.println("M (modify)");
        System.out.println("W (write)");
        System.out.println("Q (quit with saving)");
        choice = input.nextLine();
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("I")) {
            Insert();
        }
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("L")) {
            Listing();
        }
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) {
            write(obj);
        }
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
            i = 1;
            System.out.println("End");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (i == 0) {
                menu();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void Listing() // List records from MiniDB.txt file
    {
        try {
            File file = new File(file_path);
            input = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.err.println("Cannot open file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (input.hasNext()) { // If there are records in the file print them,
                                // else print none found
            while (input.hasNext()) // while there is more to read
            {
                String firstName = input.next();
                String lastName = input.next();
                String phoneNumber = input.next();

                System.out.printf("%-13s%-13s%s%n", firstName + ",", lastName,
                        phoneNumber);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.printf("No records found");
        }
    } // end method Listing

    public static void Insert() // insert a record
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Last Name: ");
            obj.put("Last Name", input.nextLine());
            System.out.println("First Name: ");
            obj.put("First Name", input.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Telephone Number: ");
            obj.put("Telephone Number", input.nextLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void write(JSONObject obj2) throws IOException, JSONException {
        File file = new File(file_path);
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        outputStream.printf("%n%s %s %s", obj.get("Last Name"),
                obj.get("First Name"), obj.get("Telephone Number"));
        System.out.println("changes Done.");
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public static void Search() {
    }

    {
    }
} // end class Project
```

I hope this would solve your problem.
Thank you!! Happy coding..

Comment: You can use the same json object to other actions performed